# Using Word of "Ready"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the word "Ready" like this:

> Ready HTML 
>       Ready Code 
>       Ready Stuff 
>       Ready Things

With these I am trying to say that:

> the thing was completed by someone and ready to use...

Is it correct to use the word this way?

Comment: This sounds a lot like [the use of "ready" in terms like "Ready Meal" which was discussed here recently](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101381/whats-the-difference-between-convenience-food-ready-made-food-and-ready-food).  We don't really use "ready" that way in US English, it seems more of a British English thing, and I'm not sure if they even really use it that way outside of the phrase *Ready Meal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are two issues here: grammatical correctness and meaning of the word.

(1) If you are using "ready" as an adjective, "Ready HTML" is not a complete sentence. It certainly could be used as a title or a label.

(2) "Ready" can mean "prepared" or "available for use". So yes, "Ready HTML" could mean HTML that has been prepared. If you're trying to say, "this is HTML, code, etc that has been written, tested, whatever, and is now at a stage where we can use it", yes, "Ready HTML" is fine.

Note that "ready" can also be a verb, meaning to prepare something or to make it available, i.e. to make it ready. So "Ready HTML" could be a complete sentence, an imperative instructing someone to make the HTML ready. Like, "Ready forward torpedoes! Fire!"

Comment: I can't really endorse your *"Ready HTML" is fine*. This "attributive adjective" use (in the sense of *prepared in advance, readily available*) is effectively obsolete except in a few set phrases like ***ready money***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. It's not common, but I think most would recognize it. True that "ready" is most often used as a predicate adjective. "The X is ready." But we often say "Keep a ready supply of X", and the military talk of a "Ready room", i.e. a room where you make things ready.

Comment: I think [a ready supply of X](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+ready+supply+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20ready%20supply%20of%3B%2Cc0) is something of a "fixed phrase". I've no idea why it's apparently become *much* more popular over the past century, but it certainly doesn't represent any more general trend in that direction. I've also just thought of ***ready meals*** (primarily BrE?), but I can't imagine the guy in McDonalds saying *I don't have a ready burger, but I'll cook one for you in less than a minute.*